# jQuery - select multiple elements with the same attribute value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a jQuery selector that gets every element with a specific attribute value - not necessarily the same *attribute*, just the same attribute value. For example, what jQuery selector would pick up each of the following?

```
<h1 name="test"><h1>
<a id="test"></a>
<p data-attribute="test"></p>
```

All I can think to try is `$("*").attr( "*", "test" )` but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very odd question.  It can be accomplished by looping through the attributes of each dom attribute, but I would recommend instead restructuring your HTML so you can use `[data-test=true]`, a data-test attribute with the value of true.

```js
$("*").filter(function() {
  flag = false;
  $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
    if (attrib.value == "test") {
      flag = true;
    }
  });
  return flag;
}).css("background","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 name="test">a<h1>
<a id="test">b</a>
<p data-attribute="test">c</p>
<p>don't highlight</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no control over the HTML as it's being created by a CMS. But this is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!